# How to merge 2 string array in Delphi

Tags: arrays, delphi

I have 2 or more dynamic string array that fill with some huge data , i want to merge this 2 array to one array , i know i can do it with a for loop like this :

```
var
  Arr1, Arr2, MergedArr: Array of string;
  I: Integer;
begin
  // Arr1:= 5000000 records
  // Arr2:= 5000000 records

  // Fill MergedArr by Arr1
  MergedArr:= Arr1;

  // Set length of MergedArr to length of ( Arra1 + Arr2 )+ 2
  SetLength(MergedArr, High(Arr1)+ High(Arr2)+2);

  // Add Arr2 to MergedArr
  for I := Low(Arr2)+1 to High(Arr2)+1 do
    MergedArr[High(Arr1)+ i]:= Arr2[i-1];
end;
```

but it is slow on huge data , is there faster way like copy array memory data ?

Comment: Maybe you were not aware: `SetLength(MergedArr, High(Arr1) + High(Arr2) + 2);` is equivalent to `SetLength(MergedArr, Length(Arr1) + Length(Arr2));`. `High(Arr)` returns the last index of `Arr`, while `Length(Arr)` returns the number of its elements.

Comment: You should use local variables to store the lengths (like `L1 := length(Arr1)`): code will be easier to read and faster. Which Delphi version are you using? Older versions use a slower Memory Manager. Try adding FastMM4 to your use clause if you have e.g. Delphi 7.

Comment: For a more generic way of handling dynamic arrays, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7102887/is-any-way-to-add-2-arrays-into-one

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use built-in Move function which moves a block of memory to another location. Parameters are source and target memory blocks and size of data to be moved.

Because you are copying strings, source arrays must be destroyed after the merging by filling them with zeroes. Otherwise refcounts for strings will be all wrong causing havoc and destruction later in the program.

```
var
  Arr1, Arr2, MergedArr: Array of string;
  I: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(Arr1, 5000000);
  for I := Low(Arr1) to High(Arr1) do
    Arr1[I] := IntToStr(I);

  SetLength(Arr2, 5000000);
  for I := Low(Arr2) to High(Arr2) do
    Arr2[I] := IntToStr(I);

  // Set length of MergedArr to length of ( Arra1 + Arr2 )+ 2
  SetLength(MergedArr, High(Arr1)+ High(Arr2)+2);

  // Add Arr1 to MergedArr
  Move(Arr1[Low(Arr1)], MergedArr[Low(MergedArr)], Length(Arr1)*SizeOf(Arr1[0]));

  // Add Arr2 to MergedArr
  Move(Arr2[Low(Arr2)], MergedArr[High(Arr1)+1], Length(Arr2)*SizeOf(Arr2[0]));

  // Cleanup Arr1 and Arr2 without touching string refcount.
  FillChar(Arr1[Low(Arr1)], Length(Arr1)*SizeOf(Arr1[0]), 0);
  FillChar(Arr2[Low(Arr2)], Length(Arr2)*SizeOf(Arr2[0]), 0);

  // Test
  for I := Low(Arr1) to High(Arr1) do begin
    Assert(MergedArr[I] = IntToStr(I));
    Assert(MergedArr[I] = MergedArr[Length(Arr1) + I]);
  end;

  // Clear the array to see if something is wrong with refcounts
  for I := Low(MergedArr) to High(MergedArr) do
    MergedArr[I] := '';
end;
```

Comment: Andriy: it does work if you fillchar the original array with zeroes. That means effective no change in refcount. The threadsafety of the concept is then temporarily compromised though. (between the move and the fillchar, multiple references exist without updated refcount). So I would not advise this as a general tactic.

Comment: NO. This doesn't work for strings because it messes with the Reference Count of strings: the string's reference count doesn't change in the process of making this copy. Here's a PasteBin console application that demonstrates this: http://pastebin.com/0a2QKAjM

Comment: @Marco: Yes, agree on all the points. I think, @gabr should update his answer accordingly, though, since `array of string` is the actual array type the OP is using.

Comment: @everybody: Ooops, I've totally missed the 'string' part. My answer is now improved & fixed. Thanks!

Comment: @gabr, when you do `SetLength(MergedArr, High(Arr1)+High(Arr2)+2)` all the reference counts for the strings in `MergedArr` are increased by 1: that operation takes time. If you're going to use `Move`, better do it all the way, prepare a blank `MergedArr`, move from `Arr1`, move from `Arr2` then fill both Arr1 and Arr2 with zeros. This avoids all reference counts updates while your current solution only avoids the reference count updates for `Arr2`. Here's an other pastebin mini-proof: http://pastebin.com/KKJ681pQ

Comment: @Cosmin, you are correct. SetLength implicitly copies Arr1 to MergedArr which is, again, slow. I've updated the code to your suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: @gabr, +1. I'd also pack the code into a `procedure MergeStringArrays(var Arr1, Arr2, MergedArray: array of string);` but that would be mostly for cosmetic purposes.

Comment: IMHO this move-based solution is NOT thread-safe. If another thread does access the dynamic array content, you'll get reference counting mismatches. A more generic solution is available at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7102887/is-any-way-to-add-2-arrays-into-one

Answer (score 8):

First of all `string` is special, so it should be treated specially: *Don't try outsmarting the compiler, keep your code unchanged.* String is special because it's reference counted. Every time you copy a string from one place to an other it's reference count is incremented. When the reference count reaches 0, the string is destroyed. Your code plays nice because it lets the compiler know what you're doing, and in turn the compiler gets the chance to properly increment all reference counts.

Sure, you can play all sorts of tricks as suggested in the comments to gabr's answer, like filling the old arrays with zero's so the reference count in the new array remains valid, but you can't do that if you actually need the old arrays as well. And this is a bit of a hack (albeit one that will probably be valid for the foreseeable future). (and to be noted, I actually like this hack).

Anyway, and this is the important part of my answer, your code is most likely not slow in the copying of the strings from one array to the other, it's most likely slowly somewhere else. Here's a short console application that creates two arrays, each with 5M random strings, then merges the two arrays into a third and displays the time it took to create the merge. **Merging only takes about 300 milliseconds on my machine**. Filling the array takes much longer, but I'm not timing that:

program Project26;

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses SysUtils, Windows;

var a, b, c: array of string;
    i: Integer;

    Freq: Int64;
    Start, Stop: Int64;
    Ticks: Cardinal;

const count = 5000000;

begin
  SetLength(a,count);
  SetLength(b,count);
  for i:=0 to count-1 do
  begin
    a[i] := IntToStr(Random(1));
    b[i] := IntToStr(Random(1));
  end;

  WriteLn('Moving');

  QueryPerformanceFrequency(Freq);
  QueryPerformanceCounter(Start);

  SetLength(c, Length(a) + Length(b));
  for i:=0 to High(a) do
    c[i] := a[i];
  for i:=0 to High(b) do
    c[i+Length(a)] := b[i];

  QueryPerformanceCounter(Stop);
  WriteLn((Stop - Start) div (Freq div 1000), ' milliseconds');
  ReadLn;

end.
```

Answer (score 3):

An excellent maxim is that the fastest code is that which never runs. Since copying is expensive you should look to avoid the cost of copying.

You can do this with a virtual array. Create a class which holds an array of `array of string`. In your example the outer array would hold two string arrays.

- Add a `Count` property that returns the total number of strings in all of the arrays.
- Add a default indexed property that operates by working out which of the outer arrays the index refers to and then returns the appropriate value from the inner array.
- For extra points implement an enumerator to make for in work.

Comment: The question here is - how fast would working with this class be compared to working with normal arrays? It's quite possible that the code would run slower if there's lots of array indexing and very little of array merging.

Comment: @gabr that's a good point and obviously only the OP could know how the trade offs work out. Random access would be slower but a for loop across the entire collection would be fast with the virtual array.