# Is any way to add 2 arrays into one?

Tags: arrays, delphi, concatenation

Is there any simple univesal way to add 2 arrays into one? In the case below it is not possible simply use `C := A + B` statement... 
I would like to avoid making algorhytm for it everytime .

```
TPerson = record
    Birthday: Tdate;
    Name, Surname:string;
end;

Tpeople = array of TPerson;

var A, B, C:Tpeople;

C:=A+B; // it is not possible
```

thanx

Comment: this has been addressed over here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6197290/how-to-merge-2-string-array-in-delphi

Comment: @Rahul The quoted answer is not the same, since it was dedicated to an array of string, and in this case its an array of records.

Comment: @Arnaud: it seems that answer uses the exact same technique I used in my deleted answer. <g> With that technique, it doesn't matter whether you are moving single strings or records with managed types, as the refcounts do not change or have to change. And it is probably just as thread-unsafe, unless you can make it "atomic".

Comment: @Rudy Why did you delete your answer? Yours was easier to read/understand that the one quoted in this SO question. There are always several ways of implementation, and if you know the weakness/strength of each one, it's always better to quote every of them, IMHO.

Comment: @Arnaud: yes, indeed. On my way from home to my clinic (here), I already decided to undelete it. TList<T>.Insert also uses the same technique.

Comment: @Arnaud,Rudy and David, what if TPerson contained some dynamic arrays of strings or dynamic arrays of other records ? Would your proposed solutions handle deep copy ?

Comment: @LU For the loop or TDynArray solutions (i.e. the two solutions in my answer), both will handle nested records, nested dynamic arrays and/or nested records.

Comment: @LU none of the solutions here are deep copy. In fact, I think all solutions here are semantically equivalent.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Due to the two `string` fields in each `TPerson` record, you can't just use binary "move", since you'll mess the reference counting of `string` - especially in a multi-threaded environment.

You can do it manually - this is fast and nice:

```
TPerson = record
  Birthday: TDate;
  Name, Surname: string;
end;

TPeople = array of TPerson;

var A, B, C: TPeople;

// do C:=A+B
procedure Sum(const A,B: TPeople; var C: TPeople);
begin
var i, nA,nB: integer;
begin
  nA := length(A);
  nB := length(B);
  SetLength(C,nA+nB);
  for i := 0 to nA-1 do
    C[i] := A[i];
  for i := 0 to nB-1 do
    C[i+nA] := B[i];
end;
```

Or you can use our [`TDynArray`](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2011/03/12/TDynArray-and-Record-compare/load/save-using-fast-RTTI) wrapper, which has a method for handling such cases:

```
procedure AddToArray(var A: TPeople; const B: TPeople);
var DA: TDynArray;
begin
  DA.Init(TypeInfo(TPeople),A);
  DA.AddArray(B); // A := A+B
end;
```

The `AddArray` method can add a sub-port of the original array:

```
/// add elements from a given dynamic array
// - the supplied source DynArray MUST be of the same exact type as the
// current used for this TDynArray
// - you can specify the start index and the number of items to take from
// the source dynamic array (leave as -1 to add till the end)
procedure AddArray(const DynArray; aStartIndex: integer=0; aCount: integer=-1);
```

Note that with such records, it will use the `System._CopyRecord` RTL function, which is not so optimized for speed. I've written a faster version - see [this blog article](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2010/03/23/CopyRecord-faster-proposal) or [this forum thread](http://synopse.info/forum/viewtopic.php?id=21).

If you use dynamic arrays in functions/procedures, don't forget to use explicitly `const` or `var` parameters (as I coded above), otherwise it will make a temporary copy at each call, therefore it may be slow.

Comment: In case of dynarrays, no temporary copy will be made. Only the refcount will be incremented. Not that big a deal.

Comment: @Rudy You're right about the refcount, of course. It's just a general "good practice" pattern.

Comment: @OK, I agree with "good practice". Note that I avoid using const for interfaces, but that is off-topic here.

Comment: FWIW, instead of using a loop to copy the first array, you could do: `C := Copy(A); SetLength(C, nA + nB); do the second loop`. Not sure if that is faster, but it **looks** faster. <g>

Comment: @Rudy It won't be faster IMHO. In fact, `System._CopyRecord` will be called for each record inside the `System._CopyArray` low-level RTL procedure. It's exactly what the "manual loop" does... And one single `SetLength` will avoid the memory reallocation (not a big deal - but worth mentioning).

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing built in that allows dynamic arrays to be concatenated.

You may consider using one of the generic container classes found in Generics.Collections, TList.

In your case you would have 3 instances of TList, say A, B and C. Then you could write

```
A.Clear;
A.AddRange(B);
A.AddRange(C);
```

I think this is as close as you can get to what you want with what is delivered out of the box.

If you are prepared to do a bit of coding yourself then you could make use of operator overloading to use the exact syntax you requires. Declare a record containing an array of TPerson with private visibility. You then need to implement an Add operator, a Count property and a default Items[] property. This could be made generic too so you only need write it once.

```
TTurboArray = record<T>
private
  FItems: array of T;
  //property accessors here
 public
   class operator Add(a, b: TTurboArray<T>): TTurboArray<T>;
   property Count: Integer read GetCount write SetCount;
   property Items[Index: Integer]: T read GetItem write SetItem; default;
end;
```

This idea can be extended into a very powerful data structure as you see fit.

Comment: One problem with TTurboArray<T> is that, while at first value, it looks like a value type, if you do `myTurboArray := yourTurboArray;`, no copy is made of the items in FItems, so if you modify the array in yourTurboArray, myTurboArray is modified too. In other words, no copy on demand.

Comment: @rudy in other words its semantics are identical to a dynamic array, hardly a problem. Having the ability to add methods makes it easy to add a function to create a copy.

Comment: Its semantics are that of a reference type, but it **is** a value type. That duality can be a problem.

Comment: @rudy Stop digging a hole for yourself. A record containing an array is essentially indistinguishable from an array. There's no problem here that isn't also present for a dynamic array.

Comment: What hole? There is a problem with the duality of such constructs. That is not something I invented.

Comment: @rudy You have not demonstrated why the construct I suggest differs from dynamic arrays. Until you can do so your comments are unhelpful and misleading. We are now entering an infinite loop so I suggest we let the readers form their own opinions.

Comment: @david Even if the generic-based solution is feature-like, and certainly the one to be preferred in modern Delphi coding, it's not using dynamic arrays... which was the point of the question, IMHO. So I guess Rudy, you and me are the only one able to chat in this SO page. ;)

Comment: @arnaud it does use dynamic arrays, just wrapped up to add some syntactic convenience

Comment: @david: so does the existing TList<T> implementation. It could just as well be called TArrayList<T>.

Comment: @rudy can't do op overloading on class types with native delphi compiler

Comment: @David: I know. One can use a function instead. No big deal, IMO.

Comment: FWIW,I withdrew my solution and gave yours a +1. I still think that solution could be useful, but there should be a threadsafe blockswap to do it. That should beat a loop by lengths, if there are enough items to be moved. Could also be used to move items when items are removed from or inserted into a Tlist<T>-like construct.

Comment: @David It could be a good idea to put the Count as a FCount property, and let the array grow as desired... Calling SetLength() for each add is much slower. About dynamic array, it does use dynamic arrays inside, but it won't directly add two dynamic arrays. You can make a procedure... But is it worth it?

Comment: @arnaud yes you would want a separate count from the capacity. The two benefits of this proposed structure are that you can use op overloading + and you can instantiate new instances automatically, no need for constructor.

Comment: I think each access to `Items[]` will use a temporary copy of the record due to `GetItem`. For instance, in a loop over all elements (e.g. searching for a value), it could be much slower than direct `FItems[]` access. Making it private could make it slow... That's what I like with our `TDynArray` wrapper, it's just a wrapper around an existing dynamic array, not another storage structure.

Comment: @David About no need for constructor: you're right, this is a nice feature of `record<T>`.

Comment: @Arnaud, rather than exposing access to Items[], I tend to expose pointer to the elements instead. Just to make sure that temporary copies never will happen.

Comment: @arnaud Good points. What you choose all depends on where you prefer to be in the spectrum of convenience vs op count. You could arrange for GetItem to return ^T if you wanted to strike a different compromise. I appreciate dyn arrays are fast but the code that results often feels too low level for my liking, at least in every day use. Fine for low level lib code, but dirty for day to day, in my view.

Comment: @David And with pointers, you may loose some strong type ability... some users are afraid of making mistakes with pointers. It won't happen with a direct access to `FItems[]` dynamic array. With our `TDynArray` wrapper, I really rediscovered dynamic arrays: high-level access is available (including hashing, sorting, and more), with some nice features. For instance, defining a dynamic array property for our ORM made it [sharding-ready](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2011/07/03/Sharde-nothing-architecture) with no need of `TList/TCollection` which expect initialization and finalization.

Comment: @Arnaud since I only ever write code for use in my org, I don't need to worry about users who are afraid of pointers but I understand your perspective. One day I'll look at your dyn array stuff!

Answer (score 1):

There is a quick-and-dirty way to do this. It is a terrible hack, but it should work and even take care of reference counting:

```
function ConcatPeople(const A, B: TPeople): TPeople;
var
  Temp: TPeople;
  ALen, BLen: Integer;
begin
  Result := Copy(A);
  BLen := Length(B);
  if BLen = 0 then
    Exit;
  ALen := Length(A);
  Temp := Copy(B);
  SetLength(Result, ALen + BLen);
  Move(Temp[0], Result[ALen], BLen * SizeOf(B[0]));
  FillChar(Temp[0], BLen * SizeOf(B[0]), 0);
end;
```

In effect, the data in Temp are "swapped" with the empty records in Result, so the balance is maintained and refcounting will keep on working.

### Update

For what it is worth: This is aparently the same technique as used in [this accepted SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6197290/how-to-merge-2-string-array-in-delphi) and in, e.g. TList<T>.Insert. I had deleted this answer, but I still think it is valid, so I undeleted it again. It could do with a lock around the Move/FillChar block, so no one accesses the items when they are being "swapped". I'll add that.

Comment: A simple for loop is better here

Comment: I disagree. A simple for loop is much slower and not any safer. So why is it better?

Comment: It's safer because it stays within the type system and doesn't rely on implementation detail that is subject to change.

Comment: IMHO this implementation won't be thread-safe, since reference-counting access of individual `string` won't be protected. You should avoid such tricks like hell. Either rely on a classic loop copy (slower, but safe), or, even better, change the algorithm to access the data in order to make it even faster.

Comment: @Arnand: Ok, the move and fillchar part could be protected by a lock. I said it was a quick-and-dirty hack. Otherwise I don't see a problem with this, no more than e.g. using lowlevel _CopyRecord.

Comment: @David: the swapping idiom ensures that this is also type safe, and that nothing bad can happen. It does **not** rely on knowledge of the internals. Arnand is right that the move/fillchar combo should be atomic, or otherwise there could be a problem in a multi-threaded environment.

Comment: Your original version was different no? pointer()? All seems utterly pointless to me. Use a for loop and simple assignment. The performance bottleneck is always somewhere else.

Comment: @Rudy _CopyRecord will copy each reference-counted field one by one, using _LStrAsg/ULStrAsg/_WStrAsg/_IntfCopy in a thread-safe way. Speed overhead won't be disastrous. About the lock protection, it would not be enough in case of individual string reference count AFAIK.

Comment: @David I agree with you that the loop solution is the clearest and even if it's not fastest, it's fast enough. In fact, even our TDynArray wrapper using such a loop using RTTI.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I handled it, though it required a slight (but hopefully immaterial to you) modification to your original code to use TArray:

(tested in XE2)

```
uses
  Generics.Collections;

type
  TArrayExt = class(TArray)
    class function Concat<T>(const First, Second: array of T): TArray<T>; overload;
  end;

class function TArrayExt.Concat<T>(const First, Second: array of T): TArray<T>;
var
  i: Integer;
  l: Integer;
begin
  l := Length(First);
  SetLength(Result, l + Length(Second));
  for i := Low(First) to High(First) do
    Result[i] := First[i];
  for i := Low(Second) to High(Second) do
    Result[l + i] := Second[i];
end;

type
  TPerson = record
    Birthday: TDate;
    Name, Surname: String;
  end;

  TPeople = TArray<TPerson>;

var
  A, B, C: TPeople;
begin
  C := TArrayExt.Concat<TPerson>(A, B);
```

The main difference here is that I use "TArray" rather than "array of TPerson".  This can be used for arrays strings, records, etc.  I find the main benefit of doing it this way is that it's truly making a copy rather than a move.  And I am using the "normal" Delphi functions instead of things like bulk memory copies, which can give me the willies.

Of course, if you were doing this in a tight loop and needed the performance, this way might not be best for you.  But I think this is the best for most other situations, especially in terms of maintenance and readability.

(Unless someone posts a comment about how there's some horrible hidden memory leak here.  Hopefully not!)

Answer (score 0):

You code works fine in the newest version of delphi `C := A+B;`.

But for dynamic arrays in older versions you can use the function `concat`. Example:

```
C := Concat(A, B);
```

Comment: Dynamic array concatenation was introduced in Delphi XE7. That feature was both for the `Concat()` and the `+` syntax. Before that, `Concat()` only operated on strings. See [XE7 What's New, String Like Operations Supported on Dynamic Arrays](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/What%27s_New_in_Delphi_and_C%2B%2BBuilder_XE7#String-Like_Operations_Supported_on_Dynamic_Arrays)

Comment: The answer would be fine if you rephrased the part where the older versions could use `Concat` to concatenate dynamic arrays, since that is not true.