# How to append one array to another array of same type in Delphi?

Tags: arrays, delphi, append, delphi-2010

How to append one array to another array of the same type without using iterative statements (`for` or `while` loops) in Delphi?

Comment: SetLength() and Move()

Comment: Based on your comments to the answers, I believe your fear for loops might be caused by a misunderstanding of often seen statement "Do not concatenate strings into one string in loops" in the context of e.g. `for i := 0 to NumOfStrings-1 do Result := Result + MyStrings[i]` which indeed is slow and may fail totally in an `OutOfMemory` error, because it requires new and ever larger memory allocations for each turn of the loop. (continues ...)

Comment: (...continuation) Your question is about concatenating two `array of string`. Note that a string variable is a reference (or pointer if you like) to elsewhere allocated memory that holds the characters of the string. An `array of string` is therefore effectively an array of references. Concatenating two `array of string` only copies the references from one array to the other. The actual string data is not copied, it remains in the memory positions allocated before. Both answers have also resized the receiving array in one go, using `SetLength()`.

Comment: See [How to merge 2 string array in Delphi](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6197290/576719).

Comment: Your insistence on avoiding iteration is a requirement that cannot be met.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having two [dynamic arrays](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Structured_Types#Dynamic_Arrays) `arr1` and `arr2`

```
var
  arr1, arr2: array of Integer;
. . .
SetLength(arr1, 3);
arr1[0] := 1;
arr1[1] := 2;
arr1[2] := 3;

SetLength(arr2, 3);
arr2[0] := 4;
arr2[1] := 5;
arr2[2] := 6;
```

you can append the first to the second like this:

```
SetLength(arr2, Length(arr2) + Length(arr1));
Move(arr1[0], arr2[3], Length(arr1) * SizeOf(Integer));
```

See [System.Move](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.Move).

---

As [Uwe Raabe's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35406753/how-to-append-one-array-to-another-array-of-same-type-in-delphi/35407015#comment58515393_35407015) points out, you can do as follows for managed types:

```
SetLength(arr2, Length(arr2) + Length(arr1));
for i := Low(arr1) to High(arr1) do
  arr2[3+i] := arr1[i];
```

Comment: Note that _Move_ is a bad choice when you have arrays of managed types like strings or interfaces.

Comment: how to append array of strings?

Comment: @fantaghirocco, I need to eliminate these loops. Because my array size is very huge. Is there any direct functions like ReplaceElements available?

Comment: there's no magic - `Move` itself is implemented as a loop - but why do you think that a loop isn't an efficient solution?

Comment: I see now the same question to @MBo :D and you got basically the same answer. Maybe the issue isn't the loop itself but can be the data structure or maybe you need a database... my advice is to take a step back and think about it

Comment: I you only want to concatenate things, probably thre's no reason to do it for real: you could simply keep track of the array sequence in an array of arrays like `a3: array [0..x] of array of Pointer` => `[0] [@arr1, @arr2]`. Just o give you an idea - it's better to use a custom pointer type

Comment: I added a comment to the OP. Your previous comment could well be an answer in itself. Good point.

Comment: If the element type is managed, there is nothing you can do to avoid the loops. As others said, Move uses a (OK, optimized assembler) loop too. You could unroll the loop to make it faster, but that's about it. It might make some difference, but probably not as much as you hope.

Comment: FWIW, what do you mean with "huge"? What is the actual array size expected to be?

Comment: FWIW, if you really know what you are doing, and you don't need the orginal second array, you could actually use Move followed by a FillChar(..., 0) of the original array. But you must know what you are doing.

Comment: @fantaghirocco, in my application, now i'm using array of Byte. so, I think `Move()` is not a bad choice now.

Comment: Even though `Move` is perfect with `Bytes[]`, my advice is to acquire in depth the technique pointed out in the [@LURD' comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35406753/how-to-append-one-array-to-another-array-of-same-type-in-delphi#comment58524714_35406753) for managed types. I think that the [@MBo's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35406753/how-to-append-one-array-to-another-array-of-same-type-in-delphi/35407042#35407042) is a remarkable point of view too. In my opinion, the correct answer is a mix of the three.

Answer (score 12):

In the last Delphi versions (XE7+) you can just use `+` operator or `Concat` routine to append arrays. [Link](http://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/2014_september_dynamic_arrays_delphixe7.html). [Official help](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/What's_New_in_Delphi_and_C%2B%2BBuilder_XE7#String-Like_Operations_Supported_on_Dynamic_Arrays) (doesn't mention `+`)

Otherwise write your own procedure (use generic arrays if possible). Quick example (checked in XE3):

```
type 
TArrHelper = class
  class procedure AppendArrays<T>(var A: TArray<T>; const B: TArray<T>);
end;


class procedure TArrHelper.AppendArrays<T>(var A: TArray<T>;
  const B: TArray<T>);
var
  i, L: Integer;
begin
  L := Length(A);
  SetLength(A, L + Length(B));
  for i := 0 to High(B) do
    A[L + i] := B[i];
end;
```

usage:

```
var
  A, B: TArray<String>;
begin
  A := TArray<String>.Create('1', '2', '3');
  B := TArray<String>.Create('4', '5');
  TArrHelper.AppendArrays<String>(A, B);
```

Comment: I need to use it in 2010

Comment: @D. Venkata Naresh  Example for 2010 added

Comment: In the `TArrHelper.AppendArrays()`, for loop is there. I need to eliminate these loops. Because my array size is very huge. Is there any direct functions like ReplaceElements available?

Comment: What is your real problem? ANY method (including inbuilt concatenation and  `Move`) will use some kind of loop intrinsically.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind that your original array is destroyed, then there is a hackish solution. It is probably a lot faster than a loop, because each iteration of the loop must add one reference, while `DestructiveConcatArrays` preserves the reference count.

This means that *copies* of the strings to be *moved* are not allowed. They are either in `Destination`, or in `Source`, but can't be in both at the same time. Otherwise their refcounts would have to be updated anyway -- in a loop.

#### Note

Between the `Move` and the `FillChar`, all string references copied over are not properly refcounted. But after the `FillChar`, they are again. Care must be taken that nothing, no thread, should be able to access the `Source` array in that unstable state.

In other words: the following does not require the RTL to add or remove references, but it is tricky and it destroys the original (second) array:

```
procedure DestructiveConcatArrays(var Destination, Source: TArray<string>);
var
  LenD, LenS: Integer;
begin
  LenD := Length(Destination);
  if LenD = 0 then
    Destination := Source
  else
  begin
    LenS := Length(Source);
    if Length(Source) > 0 then
    begin
      SetLength(Destination, LenD + LenS);
      // Copy strings -- Afterwards, the refcounts of all strings copied over are  
      //                 out of sync.
      Move(Source[0], Destination[LenD], LenS * SizeOf(string));
      // Clear Source -- Afterwards, all refcounts are in sync again.
      FillChar(Source[0], LenS * SizeOf(string), 0);
    end;
  end;
  Source := nil;
end;
```

#### Careful!

**The above is not a general solution**. It is a hack, designed for this single purpose only. But it works as expected. I tested that. **But it is not thread-safe**, although it can probably be made to be.

---

#### Update

This is very much what C++ introduced with *move semantics* for *rvalue* expressions. Just consider the `Source` as an *rvalue*.

Comment: I'm not quite sure why this got the -1, considering it provides a useful alternative to other ways for going about it, so here's my +1.

Comment: @MartynA: thanks. It is a hack, but it works. These days, you can use System.CopyArray. But that also uses iteration, and updates every reference count.